# Tweepy error with exporting array content

Tags: python, tweepy

I am looking to extract tweets and write them to a CSV file, however, I cannot figure out how to get it to generate a file. I am using Tweepy to extract the tweets. I would like the CSV file to contain the following cells: User, date, tweet, likes, retweets, total, eng rate, rating, tweet id

```
import tweepy
import csv

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler("", "")
auth.set_access_token("", "")

api = tweepy.API(auth)

try:
    api.verify_credentials()
    print("Authentication OK")
except:
    print("Error during authentication")

def timeline(username):
    tweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name=username, count = '100', tweet_mode="extended")

    for status in (tweets):
        eng = round(((status.favorite_count + status.retweet_count)/status.user.followers_count)*100, 2)
        if (not status.retweeted) and ('RT @' not in status.full_text) and (eng <= 0.02):
            print (status.user.screen_name + ',' + str(status.created_at) + ',' + status.full_text + ",Likes: " + str(status.favorite_count) + ",Retweets: " + str(status.retweet_count) + ',Total: ' + str(status.favorite_count + status.retweet_count) + ',Engagement rate: ' + str(eng) + '%' + 'Rating: Low' + ',Tweet ID: ' + str(status.id))
        elif (not status.retweeted) and ('RT @' not in status.full_text) and (0.02 < eng <= 0.09):
            print (status.user.screen_name + ',' + str(status.created_at) + ',' + status.full_text + ",Likes: " + str(status.favorite_count) + ",Retweets: " + str(status.retweet_count) + ',Total: ' + str(status.favorite_count + status.retweet_count) + ',Engagement rate: ' + str(eng) + '%' + 'Rating: Good' + ',Tweet ID: ' + str(status.id))
        elif (not status.retweeted) and ('RT @' not in status.full_text) and (0.09 < eng <= 0.33):
            print (status.user.screen_name + ',' + str(status.created_at) + ',' + status.full_text + ",Likes: " + str(status.favorite_count) + ",Retweets: " + str(status.retweet_count) + ',Total: ' + str(status.favorite_count + status.retweet_count) + ',Engagement rate: ' + str(eng) + '%' + 'Rating: High' + ',Tweet ID: ' + str(status.id))
        elif (not status.retweeted) and ('RT @' not in status.full_text) and (0.33 < eng):
            print (status.user.screen_name + ',' + str(status.created_at) + ',' + status.full_text + ",Likes: " + str(status.favorite_count) + ",Retweets: " + str(status.retweet_count) + ',Total: ' + str(status.favorite_count + status.retweet_count) + ',Engagement rate: ' + str(eng) + '%' + 'Rating: Very High' + ',Tweet ID: ' + str(status.id))
tweet = timeline("twitter")

with open('tweet.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow([tweet])
```

Comment: What's the value of `tmp` at the end of the program? Also, what columns would the csv have?

Comment: What code have you tried to create the CSV file? All I see is code to extract the text of tweets and print their contents.

Comment: At the moment the output is one big string with a link in the end. If possible I would like to assign a number to each tweet with the tweet & link being separated, so three columns with a number, tweet, link.

Comment: Use the `csv` module to read and write CSV files.

Comment: the `for` loop that fills in `tmp` can be replaced with `tmp = tweets_for_csv[:]` since it's just a copy of that list.

Comment: It's also not clear why you need to make a copy.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html for the info on how to generate a csv file in Python. Quick exmaple:

```
import csv

with open('some_output.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    writer.writerow(["field1", "field2", "field3"])
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function get_tweets does not return a value but you are trying to retrieve a value from that function which would result in None. Also it looks like tweet value will be list of strings. writerow method from csv.writer should get list of items and not list of lists. I have modified your code to address those issues. Let me know if it works.

```
def get_tweets(username):
    tweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name=username, count=100) 
    tweets_for_csv = [tweet.text for tweet in tweets]
    print(tweets_for_csv)
    return tweets_for_csv


tweet = get_tweets("fazeclan")

with open('tweet.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(tweet)
```

Comment: Thanks! It seems to work, for the most part, however it is still not saving to a CSV file.

Comment: @LucasSlemming does it at least create an empty csv file? If you run script from command line the file can be created at different location than the script you are running.

Comment: I got it to make an empty CSV, yes. However, the code has updated since to include more data and I must admit I am a bit confused at this point :)